# what is the g++ option to build ia64 binaries

Tags: g++, itanium

what is the g++ option to build ia64 binaries

Comment: Did you try `man gcc` or an equivalent? You haven't even given us the version you are on (which is probably not an issue to be worried of here). There is an entire page on IA6: See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/IA_002d64-Options.html#IA_002d64-Options

Comment: Which OS are you compiling on, which OS are you compiling for ?

Comment: gcc version is 
Reading specs from /opt/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.2/specs
Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.2/configure --prefix=/opt/sfw --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --with-gnu-as --with-as=/opt/sfw/bin/gas --enable-shared --disable-libgcj
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have GCC configured on and *for* Solaris/i386. You can't build ia64 binaries using this build of GCC.

Your best bet is to ask for an account on ia64 machine with GCC already installed on it, and build natively on that machine.

If that isn't possible, you must build GCC as a cross-compiler, targeting ia64-gnu-linux or ia64-hp-hpux (both are ia64, which one do you actually need?). See [GCC documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/thug/cross.html) for how to build GCC as a cross-compiler; be prepared for *extreme* pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-mtune` option. The default value probably is `itanium2` so you will need to change it to `itanium1` if you want something else. (This is from [GCC 4.5 documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/IA_002d64-Options.html#IA_002d64-Options).)

Comment: Reading specs from /opt/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.2/specs
Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.2/configure --prefix=/opt/sfw --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --with-gnu-as --with-as=/opt/sfw/bin/gas --enable-shared --disable-libgcj
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.2